# How can one prevent an Outlook MailItem unsaved draft from being saved when a property is added to the MailItem?

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

When one begins composing an email in Outlook it exists as an "unsaved draft". If you close the email you are prompted to save/discard the draft. Until one saves the draft the email does not exist in one's draft items folder.

I need to add a property to an unsaved draft MailItem and for the MailItem to remain in an unsaved draft state. Unfortunately, using [MailItem.Save](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.save) results in the MailItem becoming a saved draft.

Is there a way to either prevent the MailItem from being a saved draft or to revert it to an unsaved draft after the save?

Comment: Why are you adding a property to an item if you don't want it to be persisted? Why not store some variable in memory if it is never meant to be saved?

Comment: It is meant to be saved, but only if the draft is saved. If someone starts drafting an email and then 15 seconds or 2 minutes later wants to discard it it should be discarded, not saved to drafts...but in case it is saved, it needs to have an id associated.

Answer (score 0):

Trap the `MailItem.Write` event and set your custom property in the event handler. This way the property will only be set only before the message is saved.

Comment: This would work in most circumstances, unfortunately it won't work in mine. I need to be able to access the unique ID while the `MailItem` exists only in memory. If I wait until `.Write` is called I won't have the unique ID until then.

I found that if I don't call `.Write` or `.Save` then the `MailItem` exists only in memory.

Answer (score 0):

> If you close the email you are prompted to save/discard the draft.

You can add your custom property and call the `Save` method to avoid such dialogs.

Otherwise, consider keeping any custom data out of the Outlook item. It can be a DB or any other storage where you can grab the data for a particular item.

Comment: My understanding is that the messageid changes based on the folder a message is in in Outlook, so how does one uniquely reference a message if it's id keeps changing?

Answer (score 0):

I found that I can add a property to a draft (`MailItem`) that exists only in memory (it is unsaved) and if I don't call `MailItem.Write()` or `MailItem.Save()` the property is added and accessible and the draft remaiins unsaved.

If the draft is saved (rather than discarded) at some point then the property is persisted along with the rest of the `MailItem`.